# Apache vs IIS - reasons for either

Tags: apache

Question: I am at early stages of setting up Craft.  I plan on installing on Apache & IIS to compare.  Anything I should be thinking about as I do this? Reasons one platform is better or worse than the other? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Apache is generally hosted on Linux which the vast majority of web hosting services use. IIS is Microsofts platform and is much more difficult to set up as well as less common with hosting providers.

Just use Apache.